# Shell Scripts Error

Tags: shell, scripting

My assignment asks that:

> Create a directory `~/UnixCourse/scriptAsst`. Turn the two-line version,
>   above, of the substitution commands into a shell script, `subst1` taking
>   three parameters: the string to be replaced the string with which to
>   replace it the name of the file in which to make the substitution.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> `~/UnixCourse/scriptAsst/subst1 foo bar myFile.txt`
> ```
>
> should replace all occurrences of  `foo` in the file `myFile.txt` by `bar`, leaving the
>   original file as `myFile.txt.bak`.
>
> Similarly,
>
> ```
> `~/UnixCourse/scriptAsst/subst1 abc "" aardvark.dat`
> ```
>
> should remove (replace by the empty string) all occurrences of `abc` in the file `aardvark.dat` with nothing, leaving the original file as `aardvark.dat.bak`.

My code that I came up with is:

```
#!/bin/bash

set p1 = "$1"
shift
set p2 = "$1"
shift
set p3 = "$*"

echo $p1
echo $p2
echo $p3

if grep "$p1" "$p3" > /dev/null; then
mv "$p3" "$p3.bak"
sed "s/$p1/$p2/g" "$p3.bak" > "$p3"
fi
```

When I try to run:

```
./subst1 foo bar myFile.txt
```

I keep getting:

```
grep: : No such file or directory
```

Please help!! What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What does the script print for the `echo $p1`...?

Comment: Did you copy and paste that *exactly*? The error looks like you have a stray `:` after your `grep` command.

Comment: That paste is exactly what I have

Comment: NVM, it's `grep` not being able to find a file with no name (`""`).  Apparently `$p3` isn't getting the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or use the parameters directly...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3

if grep "$1" "$3" > /dev/null; then
  mv "$3" "$3.bak"
  sed "s/$1/$2/g" "$3.bak" > "$3"
fi
```

Comment: ok, this code helped. Now I get the error: subst1: Could not find the backup file (test 3). It's something for class, once I get this, Ill flow with everything else.

Comment: that code worked for me... what's the name and content of your input files?

Comment: im entering: ./subst1 foo bar myFile.txt for my tests

Comment: strange, I use the exact same command. And your myFile.txt exists in the same directory and contains some text (preferably some "foo"s :))?

Comment: ok, I see it now. I have to find out why the test isn't working. Because the .bak file is in the same directory for me too

Answer (score 1):

This is how you set variables:

```
p1="$1"
shift
p2="$1"
shift
p3="$1"
```

or in this case simply:

```
p1="$1"; p2="$2"; p3="$3"
```

Note:

- try to use meaningful variable names, or simply use `$1` directly.
- there is `grep -q` so you don't have to redirect standard output.

Comment: ok, this code helped. Now I get the error: subst1: Could not find the backup file (test 3). It's something for class, once I get this, Ill flow with everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to do anything.

```
sed -i.bak "s/$1/$2/g" "$3"
```